# Override create method from SessionController from Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding

I'm working on an api rest application in Rails (using devise) and when an user registers, a token is stored in the database. When the user sign in I have to return a JSON with this token. Any ideas how can I override create method from SessionController from Devise?

Comment: Someone has downvoted your question without commenting with reason. I would like to make you aware about most probable reason. You need to post related code in question so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to register your new controller, in `routes.rb` file

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions'}
```

Then you add this controller inside your `app/controllers` folder, as
`app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb` and define it as.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    # put your logic here
    # if you want to keep functionality just use
    # super
  end
end
```